PyArrow Table manipulation: Unnest float-array column to individual columns
I have nested data stored in parquet files.
Polars was my main entrypoint for fast data formatting of this nested data, but for performance reasons, I'd like to use native arrow, using the PyArrow library.
Here is the parquet schema of my original data :
import pyarrow as pa

document_fields = pa.struct(
    [
        pa.field("url", pa.utf8()),
        pa.field("title", pa.utf8(), nullable=True),
        pa.field("content", pa.utf8(), nullable=True),
        pa.field("relevance", pa.int32()),
        pa.field("signals", pa.list_(pa.float32()), nullable=True),
        pa.field("click_proba", pa.float64()),
        pa.field("embedding", pa.binary()),
        pa.field("title_embedding", pa.binary()),
        pa.field("content_embedding", pa.binary()),
        pa.field("n_seen", pa.int32())
    ]
)

PYARROW_SERP_SCHEMA = pa.schema(
    [
        pa.field("query", pa.utf8()),
        pa.field("documents", pa.list_(document_fields)),
        pa.field("serp_size", pa.int32()),
        pa.field("query_embedding", pa.binary())
    ]
)

For context, this is search data : for each query there is several number of associated documents. Each documents has a fixed-number of signals. For efficiency reasons, this is a list, not a dictionary so that we don't have to store the keys for each signal (in each doc of each query).
Here is my original polars dataframe manipulation function :
import polars as pl

def format_dataframe(
    df: pl.DataFrame,
    signals_names: list[str]
) -> pl.DataFrame:
    """
    df input has format like PYARROW_SERP_SCHEMA

    Returns Dataframe (grouped by query):
        - query
        - *signals...
        - ...
        - relevance
        - (url)
        - serp_size
    """
    df = (
        df.explode("documents")
        .unnest("documents")
        .select("query", "signals", "relevance", "url")
        .with_columns(pl.col("signals").list.to_struct(fields=signals_names))
        .unnest("signals")
        .group_by("query", maintain_order=True)
        .all()
        .with_columns(pl.col("relevance").list.len().alias("serp_size"))
    )
    return df

As a high level description, I'm just trying to unnest all the signals nested in the signals columns. I have to first explode on the document-level, so that each document is on an independent row, and then I can unnest the signals, from a list of floats to a struct, given the list of signals names. I finish by grouping-back at query level.
Here is what I tried to do, in native pyarrow :
import pyarrow as pa

def format_arrow_table(
    tb: pa.Table,
    signals_names: list[str]
) -> pa.Table:
    """
    tb input has format like PYARROW_SERP_SCHEMA

    Returns PyArrow Table (grouped by query):
        - query
        - *signals...
        - ...
        - relevance
        - (url)
        - serp_size
    """
    # Explode the 'documents' list field into individual rows
    tb = tb.select(["query", "documents"])
    flattened_docs = pac.list_flatten(tb["documents"])
    query_ids = pac.list_parent_indices(tb["documents"])
    tb = pa.table({"query": tb["query"].take(query_ids), "documents": flattened_docs})

    # Unnest documents fields into individual columns
    tb = tb.flatten()

    # Remove 'documents.' prefix
    col_dict = {col: col.replace("documents.", "") for col in tb.column_names}
    tb = tb.rename_columns([col_dict.get(col, col) for col in tb.column_names])
    tb = tb.select(["query", "signals", "relevance", "url"])

    # Cast list of a scalars to struct # .combine_chunks()
    # THIS IS WHERE IT DOES NOT WORK. WHAT IS THE CORRECT WAY TO ACHIEVE THIS ?
    tb["signals"] = pa.StructArray.from_arrays(tb["signals"], names=signals_names)

    # Unnest signals fields into individual columns
    tb = tb.flatten()
    tb = tb.select(["query", "url", *[name for name in signals_names], "relevance"])

    # Grouping-back to query-level
    tb = tb.group_by("query").aggregate(
        [
            ("url", "list"),
            *[(name, "list") for name in signals_names],
            ("relevance", "list"),
        ]
    )
    # Calculate serp_size
    serp_size = pa.array([len(relevance) for relevance in tb["relevance"]])
    tb = tb.append_column("serp_size", serp_size)

    return tb

I was able to explode the Table to the document level, maintaining the link between each query and its documents, but I had to recreate a new pyarrow Table. I guess this comes at quite a memory overhead. (As an annex question, is there a better way to make sure this explosion operation is zero-copy ?)
I am not able to unnest the float-list column signals, to individual columns, named after signals_names list of strings.
How can I do that in native pyarrow ?
I read the documentation, and my best guess was using pa.StructArray.from_arrays(), but I end up with the following error :
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Mismatching number of field names and child arrays

While I'm certain each signals column's cell has the same size as signals_names. I think I'm not using the correct data types, but I can't find my error.
Here is some info on types, which i'm very not familiar with :
len(tb["signals"])
>>> 12159
type(tb["signals"])
>>> <class 'pyarrow.lib.ChunkedArray'>
type(tb["signals"][0])
>>> <class 'pyarrow.lib.ListScalar'>
len(tb["signals"][0])
>>> 754
len(signals_names)
>>> 754


I cannot make it out from the docs. The "manual" approach seems to involve looping add_column and list_element e.g.tbl = tbl.add_column(col_idx, name, pc.list_element(tbl["signals"], list_idx)) - but perhaps someone with more pyarrow knowledge has a better approach.

This seems reasonable to me.
But yeah I was expecting a nicer approach. Sure pyarrow is not a data manipulation lib as polars, but it's crazy how easy it is in polars and how hard it is in pyarrow :/

"Polars was my main entrypoint for fast data formatting of this nested data, but for performance reasons, I'd like to use native arrow, using the PyArrow library." this implies you think pyarrow has better performance than polars. If I'm correct in that inference, why do you think that?

You're right this is not a very precise assertion.
I happen to have quite a lot of None values in my data, and polars will copy these data points as they are not represented the same way as in arrow (rest of data is zero-copy)
This means that the conversion of RecordBatch to polars dataframe will induce a quite important data duplication, and therefore a quite important memory overhead.
Using only pyarrow removes this overhead.
